# how to store secure application data in iphone internal storage

Tags: iphone, private

Hi i am newbie to iphone application development. I am writing an iphone application where i want to store and read some secure data (such as passwords) which is application specific. I want this data to be secured that no user can access the file. It must be application specific. Once the application is uninstalled, data must be deleted. I can do the same in android using openFileInput and openFileOutput.But how this can be done in iphone environment? What is the filepath location to access the file? Thanx in advance.

Comment: Duplicate [Saving private data securely on device when user exits application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6916314/saving-private-data-securely-on-device-when-user-exits-application)

Comment: @rohan-patel. I googled and found that there are some ways such as storing in documents folder and storing in sqlite,coredata. My questing is that storing in documents folder is application specific. Cant other user access documents folder by connecting iphone to the mac system? I want the storage which could be accessed only by application not user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to add those data (or say data written on file) to `DocumentDirectory`

Following is the link you can use for the reference:

[How to save file in the documents folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11053842/how-to-save-file-in-the-documents-folder)

Hope This Helps.

Comment: Is storing data in documents folder accessible only from application?

Comment: @GreenHorn Yes, It is. Also, When user deletes the application, it will be removed from iOS Device itself.

Comment: @MattThanx it helps me a lot

Comment: @GreenHorn Don't forget to upvote & accept the answer (only if it helped :)